# How to apply a transformation to a shape in JavaFX?

Tags: rotation, javafx-8, javafx-2, shapes

I want to apply a transformation to a shape and with method `setRotate(Double value)` I can rotate a shape. Now, how can I apply the transformation again? How can I get the coordinates of the points after the transformation?

```
Polygon p =  new Polygon(0,0,0,100,50,50); 
p.getPoints(); // output before : 0,0,0,100,50,50

p.setRotate(90);
p.setRotate(90); //not applied

p.getPoints(); // output after: 0,0,0,100,50,50
```

Triangle before transformation:

[image: Triangle before transformation]

Triangle after transformation:

[image: Triangle after transformation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to do rotations, simply add the values up. `rotate` is the "absolute" rotation, not a relative one. If you want to concatenate different transformations, I recommend using `Transform`s and adding them to the `transform`s list of the node.

As for finding finding the coordinates: You're proably be interested in the coordinates in the parent node. You can get those from the local coordinates using `Node.localToParent`:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    Polygon p =  new Polygon(0,0,0,100,50,50); 
    p.getPoints(); // output before : 0,0,0,100,50,50

    p.getPoints(); // output after: 0,0,0,100,50,50

    StackPane root = new StackPane(p);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500.0, 400.0);

    scene.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> {
        // add rotation and determine resulting position of (0, 0)
        Rotate r = new Rotate(90, (0+0+50) / 3d, (0+100+50) / 3d);
        p.getTransforms().add(r);
        System.out.println("(0, 0) is now at " + p.localToParent(0, 0));
    });

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```